# How does the input tags really work?

Tags: html

I read several articles, but couldn't really get things working. Here's what I'm talking about. The Html of a webpage:

```
<form id="LOGINFORM" name="LOGINFORM" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" action="login.php" method="post"> 
          <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"> 
            <tr> 
              <td width="100" align="center" valign="bottom"> 
                Username:
              </td> 
              <td width="100" align="center" valign="bottom"> 
                Pass:
              </td> 
              <td valign="top" align="right"> 
                &nbsp;
              </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
              <td align="center"> 
                <input class="inputbox" style="text-align:center; width:90px;" maxlength="12" name="loginname" type="text" size="12"> 
              </td> 
              <td align="center"> 
                <input class="inputbox" style="text-align:center; width:90px;" maxlength="12" name="password" type="password" size="12"> 
              </td> 
              <td align="left"> 

<input
  class="button_ok"
  name="btnSubmit"
  id="btnSubmit"
  type="submit"
  value="Вход"
  onclick=""
> 

              </td> 
            </tr> 
          </table> 
        </form>
```

say the webpage is helloworld.com, account is foo, pass is bar.

What I browse: helloworld.com/login.php?loginname=foo&password=bar

But server returns that username/password is wrong, but they aren't. What do I do wrong?

Comment: We need to see the login.php code.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in login.php says that `loginname=foo&password=bar` is wrong. That is where you need to look to find out why it doesn't work.

As for what is wrong with the HTML.

- You are using a table for layout
- You aren't using `<label>` elements to label your inputs
- You having given a form a name, these days an id is all that is required (and then only if you need to reference it with JS or CSS)
- You are using a style attribute instead of a seperate stylesheet, and quite a few obsolete presentational attributes (such as `align`, `width` and `cellspacing`)

Answer (score 0):

that form secifies that the data is passed via POSt, and not GET as you are trying to pass it. If a form wants data back specifically as POST data, that page will ignore  GET data. see [this tutorial](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML says `method="post"`, so I guess the server will only accept those values by the [POST method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29). When you browse that URL, you are sending them using the [GET method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `GET` and `POST` in PHP:

`$_GET['loginname']` will retrieve a query string variable.

`$_POST['loginname']` will retrieve the value of the input named "loginname". (This is what you need.)

helloworld.com/login.php?loginname=foo&password=bar uses GET